# How to pass a JavaScript variable to PHP using AJAX and vanilla Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a variable that holds the value of a checked checkbox. I need to pass it to a PHP file as a PHP variable so that I can run a query with it. I was told I could achieve this with AJAX but I have no knowledge on it and very little time. I would really really appreciate some help!

```
<script>
function checked(){
var chkbxElements = document.getElementsByClassName("checkboxes");
  for (element of chkbxElements){
    if (element.checked)
      return element.value ;
    } 
  return null;
}

var element = checked();  //pass it to a php file
```

I tried the code below but it doesn't work.

```
      $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url:"file.php",
      data: {id: element},
      success: function(data){}
    })
 
     </script>

    <?php 
     $id = $_POST['id'];
     ?>
```

Comment: Your `for` loop will return at the first checked checkbox regardless of how many are checked.

Comment: @JaredSmith No, I need the value before submitting it. And the checked() function works okay that's the way it was intended

Comment: Submitting what? There's no form in your code. Also, so what? There's nothing about the answers on that linked duplicate that preclude storing the value someplace. What is your question exactly?

Comment: Okay so I have a bunch of checkboxes and when I click on one of them it's supposed to get the value of it, run a query with it, and display a table that's the result of that query.

Comment: Ok, that's more clear. But again, what is unclear about the answers on that linked duplicate question?

Comment: I don't really get it

Comment: Ok that's fine, but in that case I suggest you go work your way through some tutorials or pay/beg someone more experienced to mentor you. We aren't really set up to teach web development here.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are confident that you got the right `element` (the string data of the `value` attribute) only the AJAX part needs to be demonstrated here:

```js
// jQuery:
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  dataType: "JSON",
  url:"https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts",
  data: {uploadData: "my jQuery payload"},
  success: function(data){
    console.log(data);
  }
})

// Vanilla:
fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts",
 {method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify({
   uploadData: 'my Vanilla-JS payload'}),
  headers: {'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
 }})
  .then(r=>r.json())
  .then(j=>console.log(j))
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
```

Obviously, I had to use some other backend server to send the data to but it should work with your own backend just es well.

Comment: I believe the question requested a vanilla js solution? Not clear the OP understands what that means.

Comment: OK, no big deal - I got misled by his `$.ajax()` quote ...

Comment: No it's okay jQuery will do too :) Thank you. What am I supposed to put inside the url field ?

Comment: Well, the address of a suitable PHP script on your backend. The last three lines of the code in your questions are already the key lines there.